# Where's the Ketzos Hachoshen about hashava?

Tags: sources-mekorot, money, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, aryeh-leib-heller

I remember many years ago learning a ketzos who quotes an acharon (with a name similar to sason, I think) that the monetary obligation incumbent on a thief flows from the torah's commandment to return the item. In other words, the chov mamon beganav or gazlan comes (shtams) from the chiyuv hashava.
Does anyone know where this ketzos is?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dr Yitz and thanks for this first learned question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: השבת אבידה והשבת הגזילה שני דברים נפרדים

Comment: I remember a ramban in milchamot

Comment: Thank, but i know for sure it's a ketzos. I've seen it a few times but not for several years, so i don't remember exactly where it is. I'd love to give more clues but i can't except maybe that the quote I'm thinking of is at the end of the piece.

Comment: How certain are you that it’s a Ketzos? Sefaria’s search feature isn’t the best out there, but it’s pulling no hits for any possible search term I can think of.

Comment: leviticus 5.23.